# python use kivy with mumtiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy

I don't know if it's possible, with kivy i have a window with tabpannel
i want to load tab in other core processor, it's possible ?

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelItem
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    print('calculator')
    x=2
    while True:
        x*x


class MyApp(App):
# layout
    def build(self):



        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        tab=TabbedPanel(do_default_tab=False)
        self.tabitem1=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab1')
        self.tabitem2=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab1')
        self.tabitem3=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab1')
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem1)
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem2)
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem3)
        layout.add_widget(tab)


        #load tab in other core cpu ?
        #self.tab1()

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.tab1())
        p.start()

        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker())
        p2.start()        


        return layout

    def tab1(self):
        layout1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        btn =  Button(text='btn1', font_size=24)
        btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.click_button))
        layout1.add_widget(btn)

        btn2 =  Button(text='btn2', font_size=24)
        btn2.bind(on_press=partial(self.click_button))
        layout1.add_widget(btn2)

        self.tabitem1.add_widget(layout1)

    def click_button(self, btn):
        print(btn.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

i create my window and i try to load worker function (worker it's just fake function for simulate unfinite loop)
and in parallele i want to load my first tab in other process that kivy window fore have multicore architecture

After, i want to load tab1,tab2 and tab3 in other process with multiproccesing (not threading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Main loop](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

> In Kivy applications, avoid long/infinite loops or sleeping. The
>   program will never exit your loop, preventing Kivy from doing all of
>   the other things that need doing. As a result, all you’ll see is a
>   ***black window*** which you won’t be able to interact with.

## Example

The example used *Clock.schedule_interval()* in replacement of long/infinite loops.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

import multiprocessing


def worker():
    print('calculator')
    x = 2
    Clock.schedule_interval(partial(func, x), 1)


def func(x, dt):
    print("x={0}, dt={1}".format(x, dt))
    x * x
    print("x * x = {}".format(x * x))


class MyApp(App):
    # layout
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        tab=TabbedPanel(do_default_tab=False)
        self.tabitem1=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab1')
        self.tabitem2=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab2')
        self.tabitem3=TabbedPanelItem(text='tab3')
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem1)
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem2)
        tab.add_widget(self.tabitem3)
        layout.add_widget(tab)

        #load tab in other core cpu ?
        #self.tab1()

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.tab1())
        p.start()

        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker())
        p2.start()

        return layout

    def tab1(self):
        layout1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        btn = Button(text='btn1', font_size=24)
        btn.bind(on_press=self.click_button)
        layout1.add_widget(btn)

        btn2 = Button(text='btn2', font_size=24)
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.click_button)
        layout1.add_widget(btn2)

        self.tabitem1.add_widget(layout1)

    def click_button(self, btn):
        print(btn.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - btn1 clicked]
[image: Img03 - btn2 clicked]

Comment: ok thanks for your help, but how can i get result of the "f" function ?
i try to make print(x) and return x of this function but i have nothing, why ?

Comment: I have updated my post with partial function call and added print statements.

Comment: a yes, thank you for your help !, i have question about multiprocessing with kivy,
It's real multirpocessing with multicore code or it's dummy and code run in single core like python multithreading ?